# Python3 String has no decode for windows-1256

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have an Arabic string in windows-1256, that I need to convert into ascii, so that it can be sent into html2text. However upon execution an error returns stating str object has no attribute 'decode'

```
filename=codecs.open(keyworddir + "\\" + item, "r", encoding = "windows-1256")
outputfile=filename.readlines()
file=open(keyworddir + "\\" + item, "w")
for line in outputfile:
    line=line.decode(encoding='windows-1256')
    line=line.encode('UTF-8')
    file.write(line)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `str` is already a decoded Unicode string, so you cannot decode `line` again.

What you have missed, is decoding happening implicitly while reading the file. `codecs.open` with `"r"` mode allows for reading the file as a text file with given encoding and automatically decodes all text.

So. you can either:

- open the file in binary mode: `filename=open(keyworddir + "\\" + item, "rb")`; the lines will now be `bytes` and they will be decodeable
- or, better, simply remove superfluous decoding: <strike>`line=line.decode(encoding='windows-1256')`</strike>

---

Note:
you should consider opening the output file with `codecs.open(keyworddir + "\\" + item, "w", encoding = "utf-8")`, therefore making it unnecessary to manually encode the `line`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, It took me 5 days of work trying to solve this problem, finally I used following solution.

before opening the file run this command to commandline(it is of course in linux command line)

> `iconv -f 'windows-1256' -t 'uft-8' '[your file name]' -o '[output file name]'`

so you can run commandline commands automaticly in python code using that python function

```
import subprocess
def run_cmd(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
```